# Barcode scanner data extraction

Tags: c#, barcode

I am developing a POS(Point of Sale) sort of app with C# and involves using barcode scanner.I can scan the code with ease.My question is, can we extract details such as Price, Product Name and so on, directly from the scanned code or those details have to be stored in a DB that can be fetched comparing the scanned code?
Plz help.

Comment: The answer to this question revolves entirely around the type of barcode you are using.  Unless you are using Variable length barcodes or Matrix (2d) barcodes, you probably won't have enough room to include that much information in the barcode.  Also, if you are scanning barcodes printed by other people, they probably won't have the information that pertains to you coded in them.

Comment: Essentially, this question can't be answered without you providing more information, and your research into what information we need will likely have your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making your own codes or just scanning for example a store bought product? usually stores don't store that kind of details on their barcodes neither should them, with no database would be kinda hard to make discounts in certain occasions. My advice is to be more clear on what you pretend. Anyway just download a barcode app for mobile and try to see what an regular barcode contains. That may get you going. I used to work in a store that had a database for that, i might be able to help you but need to know more.

Comment: Thank u my friend.I am sorry i should have been more specific.actually, i am developing one for an electronic items shop.they may have items bought from different companies for sale.i actually want to know whether it is possible to extract those details or do i suggest to have a DB with manual feed?It will be more helpful, if you can explain the process followed in shops.Thank you!

Comment: @Nagesh then that method won't work because a lot of different companies will have different barcode types,so unless you remake the whole barcode into a new one made by the company you are developing this to you would have a very complicated sistem. Also it's very rare to have a barcode with the price encoded on it. we had all sorts of useful info on them like origin, it's ref number but never pricing details because shops like to have the freedom to change price as they see fit. In my case we used a database which had the ref number as Primary Key.

Comment: Here, read this https://www.barcodesinc.com/faq/ the most important part is the "Is the price of my item in the barcode?"